# What is a more modern terminology for dependent and independent variables?

Tags: functions, terminology

In Wolf Prize Laureates Israïl Moyseyovich Gel'fand's Trigonometry book, he mentions that

> In older texts, this undemocratic situation was described by calling $x$ the *independent variable* and $y$ the *dependent variable*:

[image]

Gel'fand is of course an authority in mathematics and I do not doubt his statement at all. Instead I am just curious: what is a more modern terminology for "independent variables" and "dependent variables"?

Answer (score 1):

I think functions are the modern way to talk about independent and dependent variables. In some contexts, it makes sense to do analysis on equations of the form $y = f(x)$ for some dependent variable $y$, but it is almost always more fruitful to think of dependent variables as real functions of $x$. Sometimes the "of $x$" part is omitted symbolically (ie. $f(x) = f$) but it is still generally understood to be a function.